# using meteor with the Web Matrix 2's new node support?

Tags: node.js, webmatrix, meteor

After watching the awesome [Steve(n?) Sanderson's recent 3-part series about using the Web Matrix 2 RC for creating node.js apps](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/07/09/node-js-development-with-webmatrix-2-and-express/) (with Express in his case), I began to wonder how much work it would be to be able to add-on or modify the work they've done there (which includes installing and running node and iisnode) to use meteor apps?

From the very tiny bit I've used meteor, it seems like the only major disconnect would be that a project in Web Matrix would likely need to know about at least the meteor files and the node modules it installs since meteor's the entry point into a meteor app instead of the server.js (or whatever file) the user would normally create themselves.

Is there already a Web Matrix (or other IDE) template for such a project in progress?  Has anyone used Web Matrix for a meteor project?

It would certainly work (at least, I would think) as a 'normal' editor for the relevant files, but having it work in the same way as what's in the video (starting the app by running it, installing dependencies as needed, etc) would be great to have, too. :)

Answer (score 0):

This could certainly be done - WebMatrix has an extensibility model that would let you make most of the changes needed:

http://extensions.webmatrix.com/

The big problem here is that meteor doesn't seem to run on Windows yet.  As soon as there is a supported build of meteor for windows, we'll be all over getting it into the product :)

Comment: Others have MSI's available already. I'm a bit torn on meteor's separate packaging system. Would WebMatrix seek to add support for that too?  I'm really hoping to use meteor as a 'normal' node.js app as much as possible. :)

Comment: If you're looking to do something a little more node-like, you should probably check out derby :-)  http://derbyjs.com/